# Elasticsearch query multiple subfields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm curious if anyone knows how to query multiple subfields in an Elasticsearch index.  For example records:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "Good example",
      "subfield":  32
    }
  ]
},
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "Good example",
      "subfield":  50
    }
  ]
},
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "Bad example",
      "subfield":  32
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm hoping to build a query `foo.bar = "Good example" AND foo.subfield = 32` where only the first record returns.  Elasticsearch's query DSL or query string's are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "foo",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "term": { "foo.bar": "Good example" } },
            { "term": { "foo.subfield": 32 } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you'll have to update your mapping to include a nested field mapping, per the documentation.

Comment: already have the nested field type in the mapping, haven't tried with 'term' yet.  But using the bool and match it returns all 3 objects.

Comment: That worked!  And realized my `match` usage was working too, I just was querying it wrong.  Thanks!